# How to change window splitting behavior in Magit?

Tags: magit

```
emacs: 26.2
spacemacs: develop (19c429e)
magit: 20190609.1424
```

Some time ago (e.g. `20190222.1746`), magit's window management used to be different from how it currently is. For example, `magit-status` would always try to use an existing window, or if there was only one window in the frame, it would open a split (as if `split-window-right` was called). Now, magit will *always* open a new window.

Another example is that `previous-buffer` will skip over magit buffers, whereas before it would land on magit buffers.

I've been looking through the commits and so far I haven't seen any with an obvious commit message that signals these changes. Is this behavior the new default behavior? Is there any way to customize that it work like it used to?

Comment: I have not made a change to Magit that would explain this behavior. Maybe you are using a starter-kit that made those changes? Packages exist that try to take over window management. Maybe you have recently installed one of those? Also see `magit-display-buffer-function`.

Comment: @tarsius thanks for your response. `magit-display-buffer-function` is `magit-display-buffer-traditional`. So I have two machines: laptop was on magit `20190222.1746 and desktop is on `20190609.1424`. Both have the same version of emacs and spacemacs (although the laptop's packages are a bit out of date), so I assumed that the different versions of magit must have been the culprit. So I updated magit on the laptop, and it's not. So it could be any of 123 out-of-date packages that is causing this. Bleck. Can't think of any way to figure out which one other than updating one at a time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments on the question indicate this seems to be caused by an undetermined third-party package.

Comment: Can you add what resolved the issue (updating packages in this case)?

Comment: I don't even know whether @KevinOrr was able to resolve the issue, so no. (By adding an "answer" I am mostly signaling that I am done here, unless more relevant information is provided.)

Comment: Yeah that's fair. It's going to take me a while to debug, but it's most likely not a magit issue